# How to combine multiple sed commands into one

Tags: bash, sed

I have 4 different sed commands which I am running on a file. And in order to tune in the performance of these 4 commands, I want to combine them into one.
Each command is a complex command with -E switch. Searched many many forums but could not get my specific answer.

```
sed -i -E ':a; s/('"$search_str"'X*)[^X&]/\1X/; ta' "$newfile"
sed -i -E '/[<]ExtData[>?" "]/{:a; /Name=/{/Name="'"$nvp_list_ORed"'"/!b}; /Value=/bb; n; ba; :b; s/(Value="X*)[^X"]/\1X/; tb; }' "$newfile"
sed -i -E ':a; s/('"$search_str1"'X*)[^X\<]/\1X/; ta' "$newfile"
sed -i -E ':a; s/('"$search_str2"'X*)[^X\/]/\1X/; ta' "$newfile"
```

And i want to combine them say something like

> sed -i -E 'command1' -e 'command2' -e 'command3' -e 'command4'
>   "$newfile"

But it is not working. Because may be -E and -e can't be combine.

Please let me know.

Thanks !! Puneet

Comment: If you are on Mac OSX or another BSD system, then `-i` requires an argument.  An empty argument suffices:  `sed -i "" -E -e 'command1' -e 'command2' -e 'command3' -e 'command4' "$newfile"`

Comment: Is `-E` supposed to be `-r`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist On modern GNU sed (since version 4.2.1), `-r` and `-E` are synonyms..  On BSD, only `-E` works.  Rumor has it that POSIX is going with `-E` as the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-E` means "extended regex" and is a standalone flag, `-e` means "expression" and must be followed by a `sed` expression.
You can combine them, but each of your `sed` expression must be preceded by a `-e` if you want multiple of them, which isn't the case of your first one.

```
sed -i -E -e 'command1' -e 'command2' -e 'command3' -e 'command4' "$newfile"
```

A second option is to write each command in the same expression :

```
sed -i -E 'command1;command2;command3;command4' "$newfile"
```

However, since you're using labels I wouldn't rely on this option ; some implementations may not support it as [John1024](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3030305/john1024) pointed out.

Lastly, as mentionned by [Mad Physicist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988730/mad-physicist), you can write your `sed` expressions to a file which you'll reference through the `-f` option.
The file must contain a single sed expression by line (you can write multiline expressions by suffixing each line but the last by a `\`, thus escaping the line-feed).

Comment: Third alternative, put everything into a script.

Comment: BSD sed may not support `;` when combined with labels.  The OP is using labels.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron your first option worked for me like a charm !!

Answer (score 2):

Simply pipe them:

```
sed -E 'A' file | sed -E 'B' | ... >file.tmp && mv file.tmp file
```

Comment: While this will definitely remove the need for the in-between temp-files, it is probably not as optimal as doing everything with one command. +1 anyway.

Comment: @John1024. Good call. I think that answer meant `|` instead of `||` based on the word "pipe". And, yes the `-i` flag needs to be removed then. Until then, this answer is nonsense.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, fixed the syntax. Anyway, @Aaron answer is  the more performant.

Comment: @AlexeySoshin Very good.  I just added in the code to simulate the `-i` option.  Revert if you don't like it.

Comment: piping into sed again would require to iterate trough the whole file again and again. Having the fact that sed supports multiple commands natively I would say this is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As @Aaron observed, if you want to give multiple separate expressions to `sed`, you must designate them as `-e` options; they will be combined.  You can also combine a bunch of expressions into one by separating the pieces with semicolons.

Your case is a bit special however: your particular expressions use labels and branch instructions, with one of the label names (`a`) repeated in each expression.  In order to combine these, each label should be distinct, and each branch (either conditional and absolute) should specify the correct label.  That would look something like this:

```
sed -i -E \
    -e ':a1; s/('"$search_str"'X*)[^X&]/\1X/; ta1' \
    -e '/[<]ExtData[>?" "]/ {:a2; /Name=/ {/Name="'"$nvp_list_ORed"'"/ !b}; /Value=/ bb2; n; ba2; :b2; s/(Value="X*)[^X"]/\1X/; tb2; }' \
    -e ':a3; s/('"$search_str1"'X*)[^X\<]/\1X/; ta3' \
    -e ':a4; s/('"$search_str2"'X*)[^X\/]/\1X/; ta4' \
    "$newfile"
```

Do note that even with proper quoting from a shell perspsective, which you appear to have, your approach will not do what you expect if the value of any of the interpolated shell variables contains a regex metacharacter.

Comment: An example would be nice.

Comment: @Aaron, sorry, I was sloppy there.  Corrected.

Comment: No need to be sorry, everyone does mistakes ! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:** It is not always possible to combine multiple sed scripts into a single one without change. Sometimes you might have to do a redesign of your algorithm.

---

Sed makes has two concepts of memory. The pattern space and the hold space. Concatenation is only working if these two spaces are identical in both sed commands. Below you find an example where the pattern space changes:

```
$ echo aa | sed -e 's/./&\n/' | sed -e '1s/a/b/g'
b
a
$ echo aa | sed -e 's/./&\n/' -e '1s/a/b/g'
b
b
$ echo aa | gsed -e 's/./&\n/;1s/a/b/g'
b
b
```

In the original pipeline, the first sed command works on the pattern space `aa`, while the second script's pattern space is only `a`.