# Show all the file up to the match with extra lines

Tags: awk, sed, grep, text-processing

I want to print the head of a file up to a match and some lines after the match.

I know that you can use `sed '/PATTERN/q' FILE` to print the file until the pattern. And `sed 10q FILE` top print the first 10 lines.

---

Starting with this file:

```
lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet
consectetur
adipiscing
elit
```

If my pattern is `dolor` and I want 2 more lines the output will be:

```
lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet
```

Is this a way to merge this two commands ?

---

Alos, is is possible to do the same for the end of the file (ie to print the tail of the file with some lines before the match) ?

If I keep the first file with the pattern `amet` and the 2 lines before the match, the output will be:

```
dolor
sit
amet
consectetur
adipiscing
elit
```

---

source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11306/117394

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine multiple sed commands into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130560/how-to-combine-multiple-sed-commands-into-one)

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you come up with the best solution to your problem.

Comment: Could you show a testable example for this

Comment: @Inian I have edited my question to add an example of what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '1; /dolor/{c=3} c&&(!--c){exit}' file
lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet

$ tac file | awk '1; /amet/{c=3} c&&(!--c){exit}' | tac
dolor
sit
amet
consectetur
adipiscing
elit
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001 for how to find lines around a regexp match with awk.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution with awk:

```
awk '
{
    if (matched == 0) {
        print;
    } else if (lines > 0) {
        lines--;
        print;
    }
}

/dolor/ {
    matched = 1;
    lines = 2;
}' test
```

Inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5316718/2893600

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001 for how to find lines before/after matches in awk.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the file. It is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

With gnu sed

2 more lines after the pattern

```
sed '/^dolor/!b;N;N;q' infile
```

2 more lines before the pattern

```
sed 'N;:A;N;/\namet/!{s/[^\n]*\n//;bA };:B;N;bB' infile
```